# Why does swapping reference type using shallow copy work?

Tags: c#

The following code successfully swaps the values in array b and array c. Since array is a reference type, I dont expect the code should work. The execution of "testb = testc" should change the value pointed to by testa. So, by the end of execution, I expect testb = testc = {4,5}. Can someone explain why that is not so? TIA!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] testa = null;
        int[] testb = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        int[] testc = new int[] { 4, 5 };
        testa = testb;
        testb = testc;
        testc = testa;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, `int[]` is a reference type, but the variables are values that point to those reference type instances.

Comment: It looks like you think reference type assignment works differently than how it really behaves. When you have a reference type, assigning a new value to the reference type does NOT change the object it originally pointed to. Rather, it makes it point to a new object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The execution of "testb = testc" should change the value pointed to by testa

I think the fundamental thing you're missing is that *references do not chain*

```
    int[] testa = null;
    int[] testb = new int[] { 3, 4 };
    int[] testc = new int[] { 4, 5 };
```

We now have in ascii art:

```
testa -->
testb --> [3,4]
testc --> [4,5]
```

Next

```
    testa = testb;
```

We now have:

```
testb --> [3,4] <-- testa
testc --> [4,5]
```

Then

```
    testb = testc;
```

Gives us

```
          [3,4] <-- testa
testc --> [4,5] <-- testb
```

Finally

```
    testc = testa;
```

Results in

```
testc --> [3,4] <-- testa
          [4,5] <-- testb
```

---

There was never a chain of

```
 testa --> testb --> [3,4]
```

or anything like that such that changing `testb` also changed `testa`

Comment: I Can't be sure what the OP was thinking, but my guess is that he didn't think about reference chaining. I believe he held the ( very common ) misconception that assigning to a reference changes the value of the underlying original object that the reference pointed to.

Comment: I'd be delighted to extend the answer if the OP clarifies or points out that they didn't understand or I missed their point

Answer (score 2):

Array is reference type, and assignment for reference type is telling them to point to the same instance. For example, `testa = testb` means *"make `testa` points to the instance that `testb` currently pointing to"*. So your code is basically like:

```
    int[] testa = null;
    int[] testb = new int[] { 3, 4 };
    int[] testc = new int[] { 4, 5 };
    testa = testb; // point testa to { 3, 4 }
    testb = testc; // point testb to { 4, 5 }
    testc = testa; // point testc to where testa is pointing, 
                   // which is { 3, 4 } because the first assignment
```

However, the code can also be used for swapping value types. It is a basic pattern for swapping two values.